# Star Trek TOS episode with obvious stunt double for William Shatner

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

I'm trying to find an episode of *Star Trek TOS* where Kirk was in a one-on-one fight, and the stunt double for Shatner was so glaringly obvious that it was laugh out loud cringeworthy.

I believe the fight was in engineering, and there was a red fence behind them.

If I remember correctly, the Shatner stunt double did a “hurricanrana” move on his opponent, where he wrapped his legs around the opponents neck and flipped him.

Comment: Don't forget the universe tag.

Comment: Bear in mind that at the time, TV was quite different - the NTSC analog standard limited resolution, screens were smaller, CRTs added at least some blur to the image, there was no such thing as a consumer VCR, and there was no "freeze"/"replay"/"slo-mo" of live TV. For quick-cut fight scenes they could get away with a lot. Sure, it's captured on the original film stock (and broadcast prints) for us to see now, but by the time it made its way through the broadcast system and onto viewer's TV screens, it's just a blurred face we assume to be Shatner's.

Comment: I think there are multiple examples of this sort of thing throughout TOS. As I said above, they got away with it because of the technical limitations of 1960s television. I think you'll be able to find the same thing in just about any of Kirk's rough-and-tumble fight scenes.

Comment: Some of the long shots of Kirk's fight with Gary Mitchell in ["Where No Man Has Gone Before"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QT4fm0f2lZY&t=183s) are very obviously a stunt double, though it wasn't in engineering and didn't feature the "hurricanrana" move.

Answer (score 23):

[Space Seed](https://www.watchmojo.com/video/id/11730) the neck scissors are around the 4:11. Chuck Clow doubled for William Shatner and Chuck Couch doubled for Ricardo Montalbán in a fight in engineering.

(We should really get a life.)

Comment: While the fight featuring the neck scissor move is in "Space Seed", there's another glaringly doubled fight scene near the end of "Court Martial" (no neck scissor move in that one).

Comment: +1 for the answer; I wish I could do a second +1 for "We should really get a life"  :-)

Comment: KAHN: “I have five times your strength...you’re no match for me” KIRK: Proceeds to club Kahn with a plastic club from the console.

Comment: William Shatner's Saturday Night [Live Star Trek Convention](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rqb4V9GxaBo). Start at 3:51, "Get a Life!" shows up at the 4 minute mark.

Answer (score 1):

TOS: S1 E20 Court Martial possibly? 44:45 - 45:40

Comment: Did the fight take place in engineering and did Shatner's stunt double perform a "hurricanrana" type move on the opponent? You could greatly improve this answer by editing it to include a relevant video clip or screenshot as evidence.