# 'The Invaders' episode with obvious body double for Gene Hackman

Tags: episode-identification, the-invaders

This question here [Star Trek TOS episode with obvious stunt double for William Shatner](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220977/star-trek-tos-episode-with-obvious-stunt-double-for-william-shatner) made me think of an episode of *The Invaders* that features a very obvious stuntman instead of Gene Hackman.

IIRC he was fighting Roy Thinnes outside yet another secret facility.

What was that episode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be [The Spores](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0612011/), episode 7 of season 2 of [*The Invaders*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061265/?ref_=tt_ov_inf).

> In this episode Gene Hackman plays an invader (Tom Jessup) who is transporting a briefcase containing something vital: spores. These organisms will grow into aliens able to withstand Earth's atmosphere. As Jessup desperately tries to find the briefcase, the spores inside of it continue to develop.

The fight that the OP remembers takes place towards the end of the episode outside a greenhouse.

Plot description is on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invaders)

Comment: Here's some real meta-trivia: This episode as noted above is The Spores; the one where Shatner has a body-double is Space *Seed*. Is this due to some very obscure union contract clause specifying that if the title is in some way seed related, there must be a scene with a body double? This requires further research.

Comment: if the spores could live in our atmosphere does that imply that they could co-exist with humans instead of displaces us?